# App for Android 2.3 to show details of software installed on a server

Tags: android, java, software-testing

I want to have an app for Android 2.3 that acts like the [Wappalyzer Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/wappalyzer/) – which gives details on software used on the website currently visited:

[image: Wappalyzer]

I can not install Firefox on my Android device (2.3 is not supported), and so I do cannot use Wappalyzer.

Comment: See if this app works [Site Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wSiteAnalyzer). It's not documented, and I'm unable to test it since it doesn't seem to work on Android 5. But its name looks promising

Comment: That kind of information is usually done by [Portscanner](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sniffspoof#group_391)s using "fingerprinting". Two apps coming close to that are [PortDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stealthcopter.portdroid) and [NetAudit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.securiteinfo.android.netaudit). // @Timmy no, *Site Analyzer* doesn't seem to match the requirements: OP is not interested in Alexa ratings and Google results, but wants to know what software is running on the server.